# How to skip NA when formatting using scales::dollar?

Tags: r

I am formatting a table using `kable` for the layout and `scales::dollar` to add a dollar sign to the records. However, some records are `NA` and I would rather have a `-` on the output than `$NA`.

For instance I would `scales::dollar(1,NA)` to give `$1, "-"`. I cannot simply paste `$` because scales has more sophisticated formatting capabilities that I do not want to give up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `replace`

```
replace(scales::dollar(v1), is.na(v1), "-")
#[1] "$1" "-"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, NA)
```